# Speed up ST_Intersects with non-overlapping polygons in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I have a large table of points that I want to intersect with a large table of polygons as follows:

```
SELECT ptid, polyid FROM points pt, polygons poly
WHERE ST_Intersects(pt.geom, poly.geom);
```

Is there a way to improve performance through telling `ST_Intersects` that a polygon table is non-overlapping and that I want a 1:1 match? That is, once an intersecting polygon is found, there is no need to check the remaining geometries.

The polygons are irregularly shaped, so the spatial index helps but there would still be performance gains through stopping after the first match.

Comment: You mean once any polygon from the table polygons is known to intersect a point, stop searching for the rest of the polygons, or do you mean for each polygon in the table polygon?

Comment: My guess is that you would have to do this in a loop in plgpsql, as ST_Intersects does have an interrupt functionality built into it, and I don't think things like LIMIT 1 or DISTINCT will help as far as preventing a full calculation. You might be able to use the <-> distance operator along with LIMIT 1 and a LATERAL JOIN to do this, but not directly with ST_Intersects.

Comment: It's the job of `ST_Intersects` to find every permutation of the JOIN. SQL has an EXISTS operator; you probably want to experiment with that.

Comment: @Barça - yes, once any polygon from the table polygons is known to intersect a point, stop searching for the rest of the polygons.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure the planner will take the hint but I think it might work to ask for distinct values. Something like:

```
SELECT distinct on (polyid) ptid, polyid FROM points pt, polygons poly
WHERE ST_Intersects(pt.geom, poly.geom);
```

At least that would give the planner a hint about what you want.

Comment: At least in my case, the planner doesn't take the hint. Using `DISTINCT ON` is fractionally slower (8.8 secs instead of 8.3). The query plan is the same, except for the additional steps of the SORT and UNIQUE.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `LATERAL` join with `LIMIT 1` to force the query to find only a single intersecting polygon:

```
SELECT pt.id, poly.*
  FROM points pt
  JOIN LATERAL 
    (SELECT * FROM polygons poly 
       WHERE ST_Intersects(poly.geom, pt.geom) LIMIT 1) AS poly ON true;
```